# How do I fold a fitted sheet?

Tags: home, laundry

Try as many times as I can, it always ends up a mess. I have fitted sheets that are partly elasticated (just at the corners), and elasticated all the way around the edge. I can't fold either type well.

**Is there a way to fold a fitted sheet so that it doesn't end up with crumples and creases?**

Comment: I've wanted to know this my entire life.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> To fold a fitted sheet:
>
> 1. Stand holding the sheet by the two adjacent corners of one of the shorter edges. With the sheet inside out, place one hand in each of
>      these two corners.
> 2. Bring your right hand to your left, and fold the corner in your right hand over the one in your left, enveloping it. Next, reach down
>      and pick up the corner that is hanging in front; bring it up, and fold
>      it over the two corners in your left hand; the corner that's showing
>      will be inside out.
> 3. Bring the last corner up, and fold it over the others; with its right side showing, it should envelop the other three corners.
> 4. Lay the folded sheet on a flat surface and straighten it into the shape shown.
> 5. Fold the two edges in so all the elastic is hidden.
> 6. Fold the sheet into a rectangle.
> 7. Continue folding until the rectangle is the size you want it to be.

Although this is from [Martha Stewart](http://www.marthastewart.com/269141/how-to-fold-a-fitted-sheet), my wife and I have done it this way for years.

There's a video explaining the process at http://youtu.be/_Z5k9nWcuFc

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. Because the it's bigger on the inside. ;) A neat fold of these sheets will mean pushing the higher corner of the fold into the lower one, on both corners, so that although it's not flat, the sheet will be symmetrical, and fairly smooth, once folded.

Comment: "bigger on the inside" <= This alone deserves an upvote.